# Load Binary C structs from File into Swift structs

Tags: swift, struct, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have been given a binary file that has been generated by a system designed to support embedded hardware.  The file was generated using C.  I have a spreadsheet that outlines the format of said file.

I would probably be able to load this file using C, although it's been quite some time since I've had to touch C, but I really would like to stick with pure Swift (4) and load this file into the correct respective Swift structs using modern Swift convention and techniques.

I have found several tutorials on how to work with the "Unsafe" pointers and various other possible solutions but have not been able to quite put it all together in a way that will work with the complexity of this file.

Here are some example structs, to match similarity of what I am facing without making it terribly complex for the sake of simplicity:

**Basic File Header**

```
struct FileHeader {
  let index: Int32
  let id: UInt16
  let headerCRC: UInt16
}
```

**Struct with variety of value types**

```
struct MiscRecord {
  let lengthOfRecordData: UInt16
  let crcOfRecordData: UInt16
  let resetCause: UInt8
  let disable: Bool
  let ratio: Float
}
```

**Struct with arrays**

```
struct AccessoryRecord {
  struct AccessoryConfiguration {
    let type: UInt8
    let startupTime: UInt32
    let shutoffTime: UInt32
  }

  let lengthOfRecordData: UInt16
  let crcOfRecordData: UInt16
  // Not even sure if ContiguousArray is the right thing or necessary.
  // I know that there will be a static number of 5 records present in the file.
  let accessoryConfigurations: ContiguousArray<AccessoryConfiguration>
}
```

**Layout**

```
struct ConfigLayout {
  let fileHeader: FileHeader
  let miscRecord: MiscRecord
  let accessoryRecord: AccessoryRecord
}
```

All in all, there are actually about 12 total structs written to this file.  I know the offset of where each struct begins.  I am able to load the file from disk and have a Data object.

Is a Data object the right thing?  Should I be using UnsafeMutableRawPointer somehow?  How?

I can imagine that if I know the length of the data, I should be able to do something similar to a memcpy into the struct and keep it simple, but I do not know what the best way of doing this is.

I'm stuck with using data[offset..length], which is stupid because it creates a copy of the data and I'm getting weird exceptions that have forced me to make a copy, then another copy: data.advanced(by: 0)[offset..length]. (Note: the "offset..length"s in this paragraph should be [dot dot less-than], but the less-than character messed up the display of the text.)

**To summarize, the question is:**

What is the best way to load a binary file that was written from C structs into a series of respective Swift structs?

**Edit:**

This is what I've been attempting to do:

```
init(withData: Data) {
    // fileHeader
    var offset = 0
    var length = MemoryLayout<FileHeader>.size + offset
    fileHeader = FileHeader(withData: withData[offset..<length])

    // miscRecord
    offset = length
    length = MemoryLayout<MiscRecord>.size + offset
    miscRecord = MiscRecord(withData: withData[offset..<length])

    // accessoryRecord
    offset = length
    length = MemoryLayout<AccessoryRecord>.size + offset
    accessoryRecord = AccessoryRecord(withData: withData[offset..<length])
}
```

... BUT, I've been seeing runtime crashes at `withData[offset..<length]` (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION).

I was able to get around it by doing this:

```
    init(withData: Data) {
      let unneccessaryDataCopy = withData.advanced(by: 0)

      // fileHeader
      var offset = 0
      var length = MemoryLayout<FileHeader>.size + offset
      fileHeader = FileHeader(withData: unneccessaryDataCopy[offset..<length])

      // miscRecord
      offset = length
      length = MemoryLayout<MiscRecord>.size + offset
      miscRecord = MiscRecord(withData: unneccessaryDataCopy[offset..<length])

      // accessoryRecord
      offset = length
      length = MemoryLayout<AccessoryRecord>.size + offset
      accessoryRecord = AccessoryRecord(withData: unneccessaryDataCopy[offset..<length])
    }
```

..but this is bad because the data is copied twice.  (Once with the `subset` and once with the `advanced(by:`).  There's got to be a better way, and why do I have to do all that?  I know the data is there at the bytes I'm attempting to subset.

Comment: A `Data` object is the right thing to load the bytes from disk to memory, Then you start picking those bytes to initialize your structs according to specs.

Comment: XY problem. Define a clean file format and write the data in that format. Don't rely on language/machine dependent representation and encoding.And there is no "C data format". It solely depends on your implementation and envorinment.

Comment: @CodeDifferent - Pick them how?  Can you please provide syntax examples?  I've been doing something like (see edit).

Comment: In Swift, it is considered to be an inappropriate way to save memory representation into file, so there's no _modern Swift convention and techniques_ to read such a file. Please provide enough specification. Showing some not-sure struct in Swift is useless. (Though I'm sure your `ContiguousArray` would never work.)

Comment: I think I’m going to go with a mutable data pointer.

Comment: To clarify, ultimately my goal is to generate and write a file.  I wanted to start with loading the example file I was given so I could understand the format better.  I'm not sure yet, but it may be best for me to simply use a Mutable Data object and just add bits to it to construct the structures in memory before outputting it as binary.